# Android gradle: how to run separately integration and unit tests?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Currently I have standard structure of project:

src

|---androidTest

|-------------------|---java

|----------------------------|---robotium

|----------------------------|---unit

|---main

|---------|---AndroidManifest.xml

|---------|---java

|---------|---res

According to [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing)
I've placed unit and integration tests under **androidTest** folder.

Since instrumentation tests need lot of time, I placed it inside robotium folder(I use Robotium).
 Inside unti - jUnit tests respectively.

To run all tests I invoke `./gradlew connectedCheck` - it's taking lot of time.

How to to run integration (inside robotium folder) tests and unit tests separately?
I want to run these tests using gradle - it's for CI server.
For example I want to run integration tests every night and unit tests - every hour..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `JUnit` tests should be places under - [src/test/java](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) and then you'll be able to switch between `test sources` by changing `Test Artifact` when selecting `Build variants` as shown:

[image: as shown]
<sub>(source: [android.com](http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1423155717194/tech-docs/unit-testing-support/qSxL68MPv5.png?height=365&width=400))</sub>